# How to configure header's (and footer's) "Header from Top" value when using Python's docx library?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to create from scratch a docx file report, so I am using the python-docx library ver 0.8.10, with great results. When I am adding a header to the document, the header has the default values of "Header from Top:" = 0.5 Inches. I see this value when I have created the docx file and opened it in MS WORD.

So, how can I configure the "Header from Top" and the "Footer from Bottom" default values? For example How can I configure the header to be "Header from Top" = 0.1 inches? Something like header.top_margins = Inches(0.1). I have checked online but haven't found anything related.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Section.header_distance` and `.footer_distance`:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Section.header_distance

> **header_distance**
>       Length object representing the distance from the top edge of the page to the top edge 
>       of the header. None if no setting is present in the XML.

Comment: YES!!! That worked! The problem was that I was looking for an attribute of header, while the solution was on the "section" attributes! A bit counter intuitive. For the shake of documentation, the solution is:

 doc.sections[0].header_distance = Inches(0.01)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Sp_V. Be sure to accept the answer (click the checkmark next to the answer) if it answered your question. That's how you acknowledge folks for taking the time to answer your question :)