# Set Word document "Header from Top" via docx.js

Tags: javascript, docx

In Microsoft Word, you can set a "Header from Top" value to configure the gap between the top of the page and the beginning of the header (0 resulting in no gap):

[image: Microsoft Word "Header from Top" input]

The popular [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/) library provides the means to accomplish this, as per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392303/how-to-configure-headers-and-footers-header-from-top-value-when-using-pyth).

Is there a way to achieve this in [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/)?